# Initialize an array AND variable names using a for loop C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, for-loop, picturebox

I'm having trouble figuring out whether or not I can do the following: I want to initialize all of the values in my PictureBox array using a for loop. I also want the values assigned to make use of the loop iterator. For instance:

```
        PictureBox[] picUserCards = new PictureBox[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < picUserCards.Length; i++)
        {
            // Below is similar to what I have done in VBA 
            picUserCards[i] = picCard + (i + 1);
        }
```

As you can see, C# is going to throw me an error saying that picCard doesn't exist in this context. However, in VB/VBA, it will concatenate the character for me, giving me picUserCards[0] = picCard1.

This might be a really simple answer, and I hope it hasn't been answered dozens of times already, but my precursory search didn't yield anything other than how to use the For loop to work with the array's index.

If it matters, the PictureBoxes already exist (12 of them) on the form, so I wanted to figure out how to associate them with an array instead of redesigning my form.

EDIT: I want to have two arrays, a solution which takes all PictureBoxes on the form and dumps them in one array wouldn't solve my particular issue. I want to be able to determine on my own how many objects get associated with a given array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference child controls by their string name:

```
this.Controls["picCard" + 7]
```

This only works for immediate descendants. If your controls are nested you'll instead have to use [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx), which will be a bit slower (should be negligible for non-performance-intensive applications).

```
this.Controls.Find("picCard" + 7, true)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a go at it as soon as I can (the wife and I have now switched over from 'me coding' to 'us watching stuff').

Comment: Unfortunately, picUserCards[i] = this.Controls["picCard" + (i + 1)]; gives the following error:
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type  System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
Intellisense shows me picCard1, picCard2, etc. so I gather that the scope is not a an issue (meaning I don't need to .Find)

Comment: Well `Controls` is just a list of `Control` objects. `PictureBox` is a subclass of control, so you need to do an explicit cast if you want to assign the results. Something like this: `picUserCards[i] = (PictureBox)this.Controls["picCard" + (i + 1)];`

Comment: Beautiful! This is exactly what I needed and it works like a charm. Thanks for the help, I'm new to C# and sometimes my ideas are a bit ahead of my actual skills or knowledge. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using a container that has a `Controls` property:

```
var picUserCards = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Why would someone down vote this? It would be nice if you explained why. This would work if the assumtion is correct inwhich is what I also interpreted and would offer as a solution.

Comment: Truthfully I don't know, but I will be doing some reading thanks to your suggestion. I will try out your answer when I get a chance to code again later!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, won't this code take all of my PictureBoxes and put them in the same array? In the end I want to have two arrays, picUserCards and picHouseCards. Also, I'm getting a casting error (see my comment in ean5533's answer) that basically says it can't implicitly convert type Control to type PictureBox.